# Is the FIDE International Organizer title required to organize high level FIDE tournaments?

Tags: rules, fide

The FIDE Handbook has a section called [Regulations on Seminars & Title Award for Organizers](https://old.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=48&view=category) where it describes what you need to do to get the FIDE International Organizer title. It says:

> Scope / Mission: To get the FIDE licence for the organisation of FIDE,
>   Continental and International tournaments.

Now, I know that the title is not a requirement to organize a low level FIDE rated tournament because I have done so in my club along with another player who also has no organizer title.

My question is: is it a requirement for high level tournaments and if so, where is the border between requiring the title and not needing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is "No" because [Arkady Dvorkovich](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=34404449), who has no organizer title, was the chief organizer for the [FIDE Grand Prix Series Riga- 2019](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_details.phtml?event=222540), [FIDE Grand Prix Series Riga- 2019 Blitz Tie-breaks](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_details.phtml?event=225311) and [FIDE Grand Prix Series 2019 Rapid Tie-breaks](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_details.phtml?event=222541) tournaments.

However there is an additional *paid* position for "FIDE World Events" called a "FIDE Technical Director". The role is described [here](https://old.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=49&view=category).

> 1. FIDE Technical Director (FTD) is the overall observer of a FIDE
>      World Event
> 2. The FIDE Technical Director FTD is appointed by FIDE and must be a licensed International Organizer
> 3. Main duties of the FIDE Technical Director"
>
>    - To be responsible for the communication with the Organizer after the approval and circulation of the tournament regulations.
>    - To check before the start of the competition if the organization adheres to FIDE standards.
>    - To check if the Organizer provides to the participants the conditions offered in the bid and described in the event invitation.
>    - To be contacted by the National Federations as the FIDE Representative.
>    - To ensure the contact of the competitions according to FIDE rules and regulations
>    - By the end of the competition to send his report to FIDE including and comparing the final evaluation with the bid-evaluation.
> 4. Organizer provides the following conditions to the FIDE Technical Director:
>
>    - Single room (FB- 3 meals) 2 days before the start of the competition till departure
>    - Air-travel expenses & transportation to the venue
> 5. FIDE pays to the FIDE Technical Director the stipend in accordance with the Financial Guidelines for the Technical Officials.